# In Spring 2.5 <mvc:resources mapping="/xyz/**" location="/xyz/"/> is not working

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I am trying the resolve browser cache problem by using buildnumber-maven-plugin. And when i try to enter  tag in application-context.xml file and try to deploy its not working and its undeploy whole war automatically (do not understand why it has happened.).

So, is there any way to achieve or i can use  buildnumber-maven-plugin to solve my cache problem. I am using spring 2.5 version.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `<mvc:resources>` tag was included in Spring 3.0.4. So it's not available in previous versions.